# Как посчитать максимальный период пользования на Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

Всем привет!
Возникла трудность в решение задачи на SQL Oracle.
Допустим, есть пользователи, которые пользовались одним и тем же устройством, они помечены как id_user. В столбцах с датой указаны периоды, когда начали пользоваться устройством и когда закончили. Также есть столбец, где указано сколько дней каждый пользователь пользовался. Необходимо выбрать самый длинный период пользования устройством независимо от пользователя. Т.е. когда даты пользования для пользователей идентичны, то просто отбирается самый длинный период в столбце period. Это характерно для строк 1,2,4,5, но если даты пересекаются как указано в строке 3 и 6, то взять общий период пользования, в данном случае start_date = 4.01.2020 и end_date = 11.01.2020, и получить период пользования в 7 дней. Он же и будет самым максимальным для данного устройства.

| n | id_device | id_user | start_date | end_date | period |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 12-03-2020 | 13-03-2020 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 9-02-2020 | 11-02-2020 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | 8-01-2020 | 11-01-2020 | 3 |
| 4 | 1 | 2 | 12-03-2020 | 13-03-2020 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 | 2 | 9-02-2020 | 11-02-2020 | 2 |
| 6 | 1 | 2 | 4-01-2020 | 9-01-2020 | 5 |

Результат:

| id_device | max_days |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 7 |

Comment: А где собственно сам идентификатор устройства? или имеется в виду, что вся таблица - это протокол использования одного устройства? И покажите требуемый ответ. Да, что если юзер 1 сколько-то юзал устройство, а юзер 2 пересекался с ним в начале и конце (но не середине) этого периода?

Comment: Это условности. Устройство можно изменить на подписку или представить, что это виртуальное устройство, которое может быть использовано несколькими пользователями. Суть задачи, что нам необходимо понять какой самый большой непрерывный период эксплуатации устройства или подписки или чего угодно.

Comment: Первое предложение Вы прочитали и ответили. А что насчёт остальных?

Comment: Общий алгоритм. Валим все даты в одну кучу. Добавляем поле веса - +1 для начала и -1 для конца. Далее сортируем и считаем кумулятивную сумму. Начало объединённого периода - единица в этой сумме и ноль/NULL в её LAG. Конец - соответственно нулевая сумма. Всё.

Comment: Если это не является непрерывным периодом, то следует считать их по общему правилу. Т.е. отобрать в столбце period максимальное значение для устройства, но если пересекаются периоды и в разрезе устройства они будут непрерывны, то следует отобрать начала пользования и конец для устройства.

Comment: @Akina алгоритм отработал. Спасибо